# Why jQuery Tooltip position is not changing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I cannot get jQuery-ui tooltip to change position. Right now it appears under the mouse so it is problematic when using drop down lists. I have changed offsets but it makes no difference. When I look it up in the jQuery ui docs it does not show the offset function. What is wrong with my code (no errors on the page)

Current (below the pointer):

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({ offset: [450, 570], delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' });
```

Tried this, same position:

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({ offset: [900, 1000], delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' });
```

Tried this from JQ ui Docs but it changes the tooltip totally but making it all one single line and will go off the page:

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({ "option", "position", { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you specify in the first two lines are not valid jQueryUI widget options for a tooltip. Writing this:

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({ offset: [450, 570], delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' });
```

is equivalent to passing no options at all:

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({});
```

While it can be argued that the widget initialiser should not silently swallow invalid options, that is currently exactly what it does.

---

`delay` and `effect` are valid for the tooltip's `show` and `hide` options, you probably meant to use them there:

```
jQuery( document ).tooltip({
    show: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' },
    hide: { delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' }
});
```

As for the unexpected `position` behaviour, that's probably because of the default value for `collision`. When you don't specify a `position`, [the widget's initialise](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)r defaults it to `flipfit flip`:

```
    position: {
        my: "left top+15",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "flipfit flip"
    },
```

However, when you specify a `position`, but do not include a `colision`, [the position plugin](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) will default it to `flip`:

```
collision = ( options.collision || "flip" ).split( " " )
```

---

jQueryUI is full of these little gotchas, but they're all pretty well documented. I highly recommend reading through the documentation before using a plugin. Your tooltip's behaviour will probably be a lot more predictable when you start tinkering off the default values (e.g. `top+30` as opposed to `left+15` which I can't imagine you needing; or making use of `track: true` to make sure the position uses the mouse coordinates rather than the containing element). From there, if you need more specific help please make something like a jsfiddle demostrating the exact issue.